# How to visualize tags?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a data set which contains a hundred or so user **tags** - that is, binary variables marking whether a user has a certain property or has shown a certain behaviour. (data from a web site.)

```
user, high_usage, tablet, likes_cats, night_owl
A,    1,          0,      1,          0
B,    0,          1,      0,          1
C,    1,          0,      0,          0
```

How do I visualize this data? Pairwise or all together.

I'd like to create a visualization that allows exploration of this data to find groups of behavior.. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe as a graph - see my trials at https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki and http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/. (Is that what you have in mind?)

Answer (score 5):

Given that what you have looks like an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) how about using something like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) to visualise your data as a network.
You could think of the tags as nodes and users as something which connets one or more nodes.

Comment: Another possibility wuold be multidimensionaø scaling, search this site

Answer (score 1):

Every tag can be considered as a connection of two nodes, namely an object and its tag. So the task is similar to network visualization. For purposes similar to yours I use Cytoscape.  I think  it is a bilogy-drive software but the principal is the same. The interface and style configurations a very neat and allow to explore tagged data.